# 500 Internal Server Error for CSV to MySQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, csv, internal-server-error

I'm new to PHP and MySQL (and webprogramming). Thanks to stackoverflow, I've managed to solve most of my problems, the answers you guys provide are excellent!

This time I'm getting a 500 Internal Server Error each time I run my script. This script gets  86 csv files and load them into MySQL one by one. I've managed to get all of them loaded when I split them into 15 files at a time, but this is not an optimal solution as it doesn't work when trying to load them 15 at a time automatically.

According to other stackoverflow solutions, the "LOAD DATA INFILE" option would solve the problem, however I'm on shared hosting and this option is not available.

Please can you have a look at my script and tell me what I can improve to try

```
    //for troubleshooting 
    ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
    ini_set("display_errors","1"); 
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
    ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');

    //Create connection
    $db = new Database();

    $db->query( "Select `CustomerId`
            FROM DimCustomer
            WHERE CanManageClients<>'Y' and CurrentCustomer ='Y' 
            ORDER BY CustomerNumber") ; //and `CustomerId` = '1798561799'

    $rows = $db->resultset() ;

    $numrows = $db->rowCount();

    if (!($numrows == 0))
    {              
        for ($row = 0; $row < $numrows; $row++)
        {
            $client_cust_id = $rows[$row]["CustomerId"];
            $filePath = dirname(__FILE__) . '/KP/KP'.$client_cust_id.'.csv';
            $linecount =0;
            $data = array();
            $csvfile = fopen($filePath, 'rb');
            $db->beginTransaction();
            $db->query("INSERT IGNORE INTO STAGINGAwKeywordsPerformance
                    (`AccountCurrencyCode`,
                    `AccountDescriptiveName`,
                    `AccountTimeZoneId`,
                    `AdGroupId`,
                    `AdGroupName`,
                    `AdGroupStatus`,
                    `AdNetworkType1`,
                    `AdNetworkType2`,
                    `ApprovalStatus`,
                    `AverageCpc`,
                    `AverageCpm`,
                    `AveragePosition`,
                    `CampaignId`,
                    `CampaignName`,
                    `CampaignStatus`,
                    `Clicks`,
                    `ClickType`,
                    `ConversionRate`,
                    `Conversions`,
                    `ConversionValue`,
                    `Cost`,
                    `CostPerConversion`,
                    `Ctr`,
                    `CustomerDescriptiveName`,
                    `Date`,
                    `DestinationUrl`,
                    `Device`,
                    `ExternalCustomerId`,
                    `FirstPageCpc`,
                    `KeywordId`,
                    `Impressions`,
                    `IsNegative`,
                    `KeywordMatchType`,
                    `KeywordText`,
                    `MaxCpc`,
                    `MaxCpm`,
                    `OriginalMaxCpc`,
                    `PercentCpa`,
                    `PrimaryCompanyName`,
                    `PrimaryUserLogin`,
                    `QualityScore`,
                    `KeywordStatus`,
                    `TopOfPageCpc`,
                    `ValuePerConversion`,
                    `ViewThroughConversions`)
                    VALUES
                    (:AccountCurrencyCode ,
                    :AccountDescriptiveName ,
                    :AccountTimeZoneId ,
                    :AdGroupId ,
                    :AdGroupName ,
                    :AdGroupStatus ,
                    :AdNetworkType1 ,
                    :AdNetworkType2 ,
                    :ApprovalStatus ,
                    :AverageCpc ,
                    :AverageCpm ,
                    :AveragePosition ,
                    :CampaignId ,
                    :CampaignName ,
                    :CampaignStatus ,
                    :Clicks ,
                    :ClickType ,
                    :ConversionRate ,
                    :Conversions ,
                    :ConversionValue ,
                    :Cost ,
                    :CostPerConversion ,
                    :Ctr ,
                    :CustomerDescriptiveName ,
                    :Date ,
                    :DestinationUrl ,
                    :Device ,   
                    :ExternalCustomerId ,
                    :FirstPageCpc ,
                    :KeywordId ,
                    :Impressions ,
                    :IsNegative ,
                    :KeywordMatchType ,
                    :KeywordText ,
                    :MaxCpc ,
                    :MaxCpm ,
                    :OriginalMaxCpc ,
                    :PercentCpa ,
                    :PrimaryCompanyName ,
                    :PrimaryUserLogin ,
                    :QualityScore ,
                    :KeywordStatus ,
                    :TopOfPageCpc ,
                    :ValuePerConversion ,
                    :ViewThroughConversions )");

        while(!feof($csvfile)) 
            {
                $data[] = fgetcsv($csvfile);
                if ($linecount > 1 )
                {
                    $db->bind(':AccountCurrencyCode',$data[$linecount][0], PDO::PARAM_STR, 20);
                    $db->bind(':AccountDescriptiveName',$data[$linecount][1], PDO::PARAM_STR, 20);
                    $db->bind(':AccountTimeZoneId',$data[$linecount][2], PDO::PARAM_STR, 20);
                    $db->bind(':AdGroupId',$data[$linecount][3], PDO::PARAM_STR, 20);
                    $db->bind(':AdGroupName',$data[$linecount][4], PDO::PARAM_STR, 20);
                    $db->bind(':AdGroupStatus',$data[$linecount][5], PDO::PARAM_STR, 20);
                    $db->bind(':AdNetworkType1',$data[$linecount][6], PDO::PARAM_STR, 20);
                    $db->bind(':AdNetworkType2',$data[$linecount][7], PDO::PARAM_STR, 20);
                    $db->bind(':ApprovalStatus',$data[$linecount][8], PDO::PARAM_STR, 20);
                    $db->bind(':AverageCpc',$data[$linecount][9], PDO::PARAM_STR, 20);
                    $db->bind(':AverageCpm',$data[$linecount][10], PDO::PARAM_STR, 20);
                    $db->bind(':AveragePosition',$data[$linecount][11], PDO::PARAM_STR, 20);
                    $db->bind(':CampaignId',$data[$linecount][12], PDO::PARAM_STR, 20);
                    $db->bind(':CampaignName',$data[$linecount][13], PDO::PARAM_STR, 20);
                    $db->bind(':CampaignStatus',$data[$linecount][14], PDO::PARAM_STR, 20);
                    $db->bind(':Clicks',$data[$linecount][15], PDO::PARAM_STR, 20);
                    $db->bind(':ClickType',$data[$linecount][16], PDO::PARAM_STR, 20);
                    $db->bind(':ConversionRate',$data[$linecount][17], PDO::PARAM_STR, 20);
                    $db->bind(':Conversions',$data[$linecount][18], PDO::PARAM_STR, 20);
                    $db->bind(':ConversionValue',$data[$linecount][19], PDO::PARAM_STR, 20);
                    $db->bind(':Cost',$data[$linecount][20], PDO::PARAM_STR, 20);
                    $db->bind(':CostPerConversion',$data[$linecount][21], PDO::PARAM_STR, 20);
                    $db->bind(':Ctr',$data[$linecount][22], PDO::PARAM_STR, 20);
                    $db->bind(':CustomerDescriptiveName',$data[$linecount][23], PDO::PARAM_STR, 20);
                    $db->bind(':Date',$data[$linecount][24], PDO::PARAM_STR, 20);
                    $db->bind(':DestinationUrl',$data[$linecount][25], PDO::PARAM_STR, 20);
                    $db->bind(':Device',$data[$linecount][26], PDO::PARAM_STR, 20);
                    $db->bind(':ExternalCustomerId',$data[$linecount][27], PDO::PARAM_STR, 20);
                    $db->bind(':FirstPageCpc',$data[$linecount][28], PDO::PARAM_STR, 20);
                    $db->bind(':KeywordId',$data[$linecount][29], PDO::PARAM_STR, 20);
                    $db->bind(':Impressions',$data[$linecount][30], PDO::PARAM_STR, 20);
                    $db->bind(':IsNegative',$data[$linecount][31], PDO::PARAM_STR, 20);
                    $db->bind(':KeywordMatchType',$data[$linecount][32], PDO::PARAM_STR, 20);
                    $db->bind(':KeywordText',$data[$linecount][33], PDO::PARAM_STR, 20);
                    $db->bind(':MaxCpc',$data[$linecount][34], PDO::PARAM_STR, 20);
                    $db->bind(':MaxCpm',$data[$linecount][35], PDO::PARAM_STR, 20);
                    $db->bind(':OriginalMaxCpc',$data[$linecount][36], PDO::PARAM_STR, 20);
                    $db->bind(':PercentCpa',$data[$linecount][37], PDO::PARAM_STR, 20);
                    $db->bind(':PrimaryCompanyName',$data[$linecount][38], PDO::PARAM_STR, 20);
                    $db->bind(':PrimaryUserLogin',$data[$linecount][39], PDO::PARAM_STR, 20);
                    $db->bind(':QualityScore',$data[$linecount][40], PDO::PARAM_STR, 20);
                    $db->bind(':KeywordStatus',$data[$linecount][41], PDO::PARAM_STR, 20);
                    $db->bind(':TopOfPageCpc',$data[$linecount][42], PDO::PARAM_STR, 20);
                    $db->bind(':ValuePerConversion',$data[$linecount][43], PDO::PARAM_STR, 20);
                    $db->bind(':ViewThroughConversions',$data[$linecount][44], PDO::PARAM_STR, 20);

                    $db->execute();
                }
                $linecount++;                   
            }
            $db->endTransaction();
            fclose($csvfile);
        }
    }

    $db = NULL;

    die("END");         
    ?>
```

Comment: I would advise against Insert IGNORE, a better way is to use a try{ }catch for the duplicates.  The reason is you could have a db error and not see it with ignore

Comment: One of your main problem is you have $db->query(), $db->bind(), $db->execute() ~ should be $stmt = $db->prepare(), $stmt->bindParam(), $stmt->execute(), This is PDO database driver right?  MySqli doesn't have named placeholders, unless your using so kind of db wrapper, then just ignore me.

Answer (score 0):

Hi like I said in my comment

```
try{
    $db->execute(....);
}catch( \PDOException $e ){
   if($e->getCode() != 23000){  //you'll have to check this code, but pretty sure it's the correct one for duplicate key, basically you don't want to do the insert when the row is in the database right? this way you re-throw any other errors, as I believe IGNORE ignores all errors not just the duplicate key. 
     throw new \PDOException($e->getMessage(), $e->getCode(), $e); //rethrow other errors.
  }
}
```

Also the other big change I would make is assign keys to the csv array, the way to do that would be make an array of the db headers in the order they will be in the csv file.

```
$fields = array(
   'AccountDescriptiveName',
   'AccountTimeZoneId',
   'AdGroupId',
   'AdGroupName',
   'AdGroupStatus',
    .....

  $placeholders = array_map(function( $item ){
      //just adds the ':' for the placeholders.
       return ':'.$item;
  }, $fields);
```

Then

```
  while(false !== ( $data = fgetcsv($csvfile) ) ) //combine this all
  {
       //remove the nested array I don't think you need the line count bit, what you are doing there with the $data = array() is saving it all into an array and then writing it out, if you don't need the data later ( assuming this based on the die statement ) you can potentially save a lot of memory by recycling $data on each loop .
    $data =  array_combine($fields, $data);
     .....

    //note you might need to check this if you have blank lines.  Otherwise it can blow up

   if( count( $data ) == $num_fields ) //count fields outside the loop $num_fields = count( $fields );
      $data =  array_combine( $placeholders, $data);
```

Then you can just do this for your query

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO STAGINGAwKeywordsPerformance ( ".implode(",", $fields) ." )VALUES( ".implode(",", $placeholders)." ) ";

$stmt = $db->prepare( $sql );  //fix these. you had just query() which executes the query here and the you execute the query on the PDOStatement object no the PDO object 
$stmt->execute ( $data );
```

Also change this or rename the same variable in my example ( you'll have problems if they are same name ) I always use like $i or the like for increments.

```
for ($row = 0; $row < $numrows; $row++)
        {
```

Explanation:

Right now your writing each field out, so if you change one there is around 4 places you'll have to update the code, also a lot of room for spelling error and such, this way you just change the fields and as long as the csv match your good.

I haven't tested this code, but I do the same all day long basically what you want is this array structure for $data, it will be much easier to handle..

```
$data = array(
   ':AccountDescriptiveName' => 'my name',
   ':AccountTimeZoneId' => 62,
   ':AdGroupId' => 1,
   ':AdGroupName'  => 'group1',
   ':AdGroupStatus' => 1,
.....
```

Comment: Thank You @ArtisiticPhoenix, I will try your suggestions and put my results back here.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you meant in your second comment about DB wrapper. I've created a database class for using the PDO Database Driver written according to http://culttt.com/2012/10/01/roll-your-own-pdo-php-class/  for the rest I've adapted my code according to the suggestions, but am still getting the internal server error.

Comment: That's a database wrapper.  It's just some of the PDO calls you your code was wrong but if you have a class to manage the PDOstatment part it might be fine like that.